# How to validate array object in Laravel with?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have this JSON array list and want to validate to ensure `min_distance` and `max_distance` in array 0 are ways less than array 1... and vice-versa

```
array:2 [
  "name" => "Run"
  "pricing" => array:3 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "min_distance" => "1.0000"
      "max_distance" => "2.0000"
      "assign" => "8.0000"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
      "min_distance" => "3.0000"
      "max_distance" => "4.0000"
      "assign" => "2.0000"
    ]
    2 => array:3 [
      "min_distance" => "4.0000"
      "max_distance" => "5.0000"
      "assign" => "50.0000"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
if($arr['pricing'][0]['min_distance'] > $arr['pricing'][1]['min_distance'] || $arr['pricing'][0]['max_distance'] > $arr['pricing'][1]['max_distance']) {
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']);
}
```

and in your view:

```
@if($errors->any())
<h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
```

Comment: Please how to check if the index is dynamic.

Comment: @Asfos22 with for loop!